# Gradle NPE during build?

Tags: java, gradle, properties, nullpointerexception, dependencies

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to build my project. I currently declare my dependencies as `properties` in top level, then reference in sub-modules (shown below):

**Error:**

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myProject'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.flatten(GUtil.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.flatten(GUtil.java:66)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.collectionize(GUtil.java:93)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil$collectionize.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.methodMissing(DefaultDependencyHandler.groovy:
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.invokeMethod(DefaultDependencyHandler.groovy)
```

**Top level declaration:**

```
ext.libraries = [

   junit: 'junit:junit:4.12',
   mockito: 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'

]
```

**Referencing property in sub-module:**

```
testCompile([
   libraries.junit,
   libraries.mockito

])
```

I am getting the error at the `testCompile([` line in the sub-module. What could be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script works correctly with gradle 2.8:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

ext.libraries = [

   junit: 'junit:junit:4.12',
   mockito: 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'

]

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile(
    [
      libraries.junit,
      libraries.mockito
    ]
  )
}
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34898245) here.

Comment: Thanks. Although I have the testcompile block in a submodule's build.gradle?

Comment: Have a look at the demo.